# One and half space problem in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, line-spacing

I have checked some questions but none of the answers solved my problem.
I am pretty new to latex and I am trying to format my thesis with the style file provided by the university. While whole thesis is completely fine in terms of style, bibliography entries have 1,5 line spacing rather than single space.

I believe the part that refers to bibliography is the following (as I tried to change some parts of it and saw the effects of these changes in the output):

```
\def\thebibliography#1{
 \chapter*{\vspace{-27mm}\bibname\@mkboth
   {\uppercase{\refname}}{\uppercase{\bibname}}}
   \vspace{-3mm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
   \list
   {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}
   \singlespace
   \setlength{\itemsep}{0.6cm}
   \leftmargin\labelwidth
   \advance\leftmargin 4mm
   %\advance\leftmargin\bibindent
   \itemindent -\bibindent
   \listparindent \itemindent
   \parsep \z@
   \usecounter{enumi}}
   \def\newblock{}
   \sloppy
   \sfcode`\.=1000\relax
   }
```

I have also found following in the style file, but changing these values did not change spacing:

```
\newcommand{\singlespace}{\renewcommand{\@defaultbaselinestretch}{1.1}}
\newcommand{\oneandhalfspace}{\renewcommand{\@defaultbaselinestretch}{1.5}}
\newcommand{\doublespace}{\renewcommand{\@defaultbaselinestretch}{1.7}}
```

So the question is, why do I get oneandhalfspace even though singlespace is specified? A screenshot from the output is also attached

[image: Example bibliography entries]

I just need to decrease the line spacing in entries (not between entries). I am open to all suggestions. I can also provide complete tex and style file if necessary. I have similar problem with a title (which comes out in 12 pt instead of 14) but if this is solved I believe I can manage the other one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not sufficient to answer your question. Instead of posting fragments of code from the style file, post a link to the style file and edit your question to show a minimal compilable document (NOT your whole thesis) that can reproduce the problem. The document should start with `\documentclass{...}`, and load *only* the packages needed to make the example compile, probably your thesis style file and the package you are using for your bibliography, nothing else.

Comment: i would change the itemsep value from 0.6 cm (9th line of the code you provided) to 0.3 or whatever...  do it and check the results

Comment: @koleygr That will change the separation between items and not within them, so just what the OP doesn't want.

Comment: Your `\singlespacing` command simply redefines another command. Your code doesn't show  how `\@defaultbaselinestretch` is defined and used, so it is not possible to say if it is actually called in the list processing. Try `\singlespace\selectfont` or instead of the `\singlespace` `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.1}\selectfont`

Comment: Actually what @UlrikeFischer suggested worked. I've just changed \singlespace to \linespread{1}\selectfont and it is okay now. Thanks a lot for the help! I'm not sure if the font is same but that I can figure out on my own. I can choose this comment as the best answer if it is entered as an answer. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\singlespacing` command simply redefines another command. Your code doesn't show how this `\@defaultbaselinestretch` is defined and -- more importantly -- how it is used, so it is not possible to say if it is actually called in the list processing (probably not) and what to do to get it called.

So try instead of the `\singlespace`

```
 \renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.1}\selectfont
```

or

```
\linespread{1.1}\selectfont
```